# Override auth redirection of apis url in laravel with auth passport system

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

I have created some apis thats work fine. Now when someone hit that protected apis url that have get request on web browser then it redirect to login of auth system. How can I override this functionality?

**Full Details**

I am working in laravel application in which I have implemented passport and auth system. This project has not any web interface till date.
This is my api.php

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api'],'namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => '/v1'], function () {
    Route::get('/user/profile', 'UserController@profile');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'], 'namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => '/v1'], function () {
    Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create');
    Route::post('/auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/auth/password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@getResetToken');
    Route::post('/auth/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

and this is my web.php

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

When I hit

> {{site_url}}/api/v1/user/profile

without passing or with invalid access token in postman then it returns the following error(**this is OK**).

```php
{"status":"fail","success":0,"error":401,"message":"Invalid Token!"}
```

But when I hit this url in web browser then it redirect me to login page.

Comment: So what you want to show in the browser?

Comment: something like {"status":"fail","success":0,"error":401,"message":"Invalid Token!"} or just show unautorized. But not a web page or let say in future I have home page then the redirection to site url but apis should not effected.

Comment: It's not supposed to be, Laravel default sends to login route for 401 requests of browsers. Simply you can edit your login page and write whatever you want.

Comment: So as per you say after redirect to login then I can show them the whatever thing I want to show. like if expects json then error otherwise Not Found or site home page.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding these functions to `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```php
public function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception){
    if($request->expectsJson()){
        return response()->json('Please login',401);
    }
    return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
}

public function unauthorized($request, AuthorizationException $exception){
    if($request->expectsJson()){
        return response()->json("You don't have permission to do this",401);
    }
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

Comment: a browser never expects json by default!

Comment: and one more thing I have done this that why when someone enter invalid token then I send 401 error. But my question is what about in browser?

Comment: what i understood from your question is that you want to handle the redirection of failed authentication to custom url, if so, then these functions work, just replace `return redirect()->guest('admin/login');` to your custom route

Comment: I understand what I need to do. I did this before but forget. anyway you give me the idea.

Comment: I just need to change the definition of the function to this.     protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['status' => "fail","success" => 0,  "error" => 401, 'message' => trans('response.invalid_token')], 401)
                    :abort(404);
    }

Comment: You have also need to add : 

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

to \App\Exception\Handler.php as well.